# Display running time

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, jsfiddle

I wanted to use D3.js to display the running time for an upcoming project that I'm doing. It works just fine on *localhost*, but my JSFiddle - it doesn't update automatically. Is there an issue with how I have things setup for JSFiddle?

I added external resources for jQuery & D3js. When I inspect element, source code for *result* in JSFiddle looks the same as in *localhost*

**[JSFiddle for running time](http://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/NQCbu/5/)**.

```
var d, h, m, s, DayNight;
currtime();

$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval("currtime()", 1000);
});

d3.select("#runtime")
    .append("text")
    .text("Current time: ")
    .append("span")
    .attr("id", "time")
    .text(h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " " + DayNight);

function currtime() {
    d = new Date();
    h = d.getHours();
    m = d.getMinutes();
    s = d.getSeconds();
    DayNight = "PM";
    if (h>12) h=h-12;
    if (h < 12) DayNight = "AM";
    if (m <= 9) m = "0" + m;
    if (s <= 9) s = "0" + s;

    d3.select("#runtime")
        .select("#time")
        .text(h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " " + DayNight);
};
```

Comment: You are going to have `14:XX:XX PM`

Comment: Oh gosh. I probably wouldn't even have noticed that. Thanks. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the JavaScript console you can see what is going on.  `currtime() is not defined`  Also eval is evil (even when inside `setInterval()`).  Here is an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NQCbu/8/) that works.  Change this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval("currtime()", 1000);
});
```

to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(currtime, 1000);
});
```

Comment: "eval is evil" not sure what that means.

Comment: Works great. I didn't even think of looking at my console while in JSFiddle.... <doh>

Comment: http://jslinterrors.com/eval-is-evil/ <-it's a really good habit to get into every time you see a string being evaluated at code, to call it out

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the link and the help.